# How to use regex to find all disk numbers that are offline in a string

Tags: node.js, regex

I'm using nodejs to execute a certain cmd script, however the output from cmd is in string format and I need to access which disks numbers have the status offline.

for example, the string i need to search in is

"\r\nMicrosoft DiskPart version 10.0.19041.610\r\n\r\nCopyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.\r\nOn computer: DESKTOP-HACFL5A\r\n\r\n  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt\r\n  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---\r\n  Disk 0    Online          238 GB  1024 KB        *\r\n  Disk 1    Online           14 GB     9 GB        *\r\n\r\nDisk 1 is now the selected disk.\r\n"

By using the following regex i get the information that there are 2 disks online, but how do i get their disk numbers? I need the regex output to store all the offline disk numbers in an array.

```
var str = JSON.stringify(stdout);
var matches = str.match( /Online/g )
console.log("matches is: ", matches)
```

matches is:  [ 'Online', 'Online' ]

Comment: You could use a capture group `\bDisk (\d+) Online\b` https://regex101.com/r/O208OB/1 Note that there is no `offline` in the text.

Comment: Ye was a bad example since there was only online disks, thanks for the quick answer. I will give it a try :)

Comment: What does the string with the Offline disk(s) look like?

Comment: Exactly the same but instead of "Online" its "Offline"

Comment: Then use `\bDisk (\d+) Offline\b` See https://jsfiddle.net/cdkvhoxe/

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
\d+(?= Offline)
```

```js
var str = `Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.19041.610

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: DESKTOP-HACFL5A

 Disk ### Status Size Free Dyn Gpt
 -------- ------------- ------- ------- --- ---
 Disk 0 Offline 238 GB 1024 KB *
 Disk 1 Online 14 GB 9 GB *

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.`;

var matches = str.match( /\d+(?= Offline)/g );

console.log("matches is: ", matches)
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work with the following code

```
var str = JSON.stringify(stdout);
const t = str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim()
const regex = /\bDisk (\d+) Online\b/g;
console.log(Array.from(t.matchAll(regex), m => m[1]));
```

Thanks everyone.